# uninitialized constant UsersController::User

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Where do I initialize the constant? I thought it was just in the controller.

Error

```
uninitialized constant UsersController::User
```

Users Controller

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
      def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
      end
      def new
      end
    end
```

routes

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

  get "users/new"
 resources :users
  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/signup', to: 'users#new'

  match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
```

user.rb

```
 class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
      has_secure_password
      before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
      validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
      VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
      validates :email, presence: true,
      format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
      uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
      validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
      validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
    end
```

This might help
I am also getting

```
The action 'index' could not be found for UsersController
```

when I go to the users page, but when I go to users/1 I get the above error.

Comment: Would you post the code in app/models/user.rb ?

Comment: a stack trace would be useful...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here -

1. Your `AdminUser` model should be called `User`, as it's defined in `user.rb`, and your `UsersController` is trying to find them, which is why you get the `uninitialized constant UsersController::User` error. The controller will not define the `User` class for you.
2. You haven't defined an `index` action in `UsersController`, but you've defined a route for it. When you declare a resource in your `routes.rb` file, Rails will create 7 routes by default, which point to specific actions in the controller - `index`, `show`, `new`, `edit`, `create`, `update`, and `delete`. You can prevent Rails from defining one or more of the routes, via the `:only` parameter - e.g. `resources :users, :only => [:new, :show]` You can see the routes that are defined, as well as the controller actions they will call with `rake routes`. `http://localhost:3000/users` will hit the `UsersController#index` action by default, while `http://localhost:3000/users/1` will hit the `UsersController#show` action by default, passing `1` as the `id` param.